# Wep API fails to return data from HttpClient call

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have not been able to figure out why the following issue is happening:

I have created a simple web api controller (.Net Framework 4.6.1)

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/<controller>
    public async Task<string> Get()
    {
        var url = "http://api.plos.org/search?q=title:DNA";
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url))
            {
                using (var content = response.Content)
                {
                    var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return result;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code above I get the following error after about 20 seconds.

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred while sending the request.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\r\n   at restapitest2.Controllers.TestController.<Get>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\\restapitest2\\restapitest2\\Controllers\\TestController.cs:line 19\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__1`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__15.MoveNext()",
    "InnerException": {
        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "Unable to connect to the remote server",
        "ExceptionType": "System.Net.WebException",
        "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)",
        "InnerException": {
            "Message": "An error has occurred.",
            "ExceptionMessage": "A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 216.74.38.80:80",
            "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException",
            "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)"
        }
    }
}
```

When I create a dotnet core web api controller the same code works fine.

This is what the dot net core code looks like.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Get()
    {
        var url = "http://api.plos.org/search?q=title:DNA";
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url))
            {
                using (var content = response.Content)
                {
                    var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return result;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is strange is that if I use an internal URL both api solutions return data.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Maybe because your .NET Core Web API is running on HTTPS & .NET Framework Web API is running on HTTP.

Comment: I enabled SSL on the .Net Framework project but still get the same error

Comment: Did you check the proxy as I mentioned in the updated answer?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you aren't behind a proxy?

Are you sure that your DNS server can look up `api.plos.org`?

Check your exception more deeply, checking its inner exceptions will help you understand is that a DNS problem or a proxy problem.

If you are behind a proxy don't forget to set proxy for HttpClient.

**Update 1:**

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond 216.74.38.80:80

I faced this error every time that I got a proxy on my machine. Since you said "if you run fiddler everything works fine" I assume you need to remove proxy settings from windows `Lan Settings`.

1. In the `run` type `inetcpl.cpl` and press enter.
2. Go to the `Connections` tab.
3. At the bottom of the dialog, there is `Lan Settings` button. Click on it.
4. In the LAN settings dialog make sure you have unchecked all the checkboxes especially `use proxy for your lan`.

**Off-topic recommendation:**

> HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout
>   the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for
>   every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy
>   loads. This will result in SocketException errors. Below is an example
>   using HttpClient correctly.

```
public class GoodController : ApiController
{
    // OK
    private static readonly HttpClient HttpClient;

    static GoodController()
    {
        HttpClient = new HttpClient();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the off topic tip. The fact is I can retrieve data from a .Net Core web api, from a console app, via post man and in a web browser on my local machine from the specified URL. It's just the .Net Framework web api giving the problem. If I run fiddler the problem also goes away. The stack trace doesn't give any great feedback.

Comment: Yes it may still turn out to be a proxy issue.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the entire exception including the stack trace

Comment: @Andrew I see and I updated my answer. Take a look on it.

Comment: I have checked the lan settings and the proxy is unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out that the code works, which could either be HTTPS issues or Proxy, I've re-written the code to the following to include HTTPS in the URL

```
 [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Get()
    {
        var url = "https://api.plos.org/search?q=title:DNA";

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);

        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request))
        {
            var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            return Ok(content);
        }
    }
```

But I would use IHttpClientFactory due to the problems it solves for sockets, not HttpClient.

In order to use the IHttpClientFactory do the following

Add the service to the ConfigureServices.cs

```
  services.AddHttpClient();
```

then inject the call into the constructor

```
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _clientFactory;

    public ValuesController(IHttpClientFactory clientFactory)
    {
        _clientFactory = clientFactory;
    }
```

then your API call would be the following

```
var url = "https://api.plos.org/search?q=title:DNA";

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);

        var httpClient = _clientFactory.CreateClient();

        using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request))
        {
            var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            return Ok(content);
        }
```