# I have web api which is hoted on azure. get request working from postman and simple get request. But it not working from c# http get call

Tags: c#, azure

I have a web api https://itcportalapi.azurewebsites.net/portal/api/User/GetSecurityQuestions

which is hosted on azure web app. now it working in simple get call through the browser and postman. but it not working thorough the http async get call.

Remort server debug but same problem. 
previously in some other azure account same code is working.
same web API code running in local is able to consume by the c# HTTP get the asynce code.

```cs
public static async Task<string> ApiRequest(string url)
{
    HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = null;
    string responseObj = string.Empty;
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(Constants.JSONContentType));
            responseMessage = await client.GetAsync(url);
            if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                responseObj = responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            }
            else
            {
                log.Error("ApiRequest -the current request URL " + url + " and Status Code:" + responseMessage.StatusCode + responseMessage.ReasonPhrase);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error("ApiRequest:" + ex.Message + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        return responseObj;
    }
}
```

```cs
public async Task<ActionResult> ForgotPassword()
{
    UserSecurityQuestion model = new Models.UserSecurityQuestion();
    model.SQuestions = await this.GetSecurityQuestions();
    return View(model);
}
```

below exception is coming
which is hosted on the azure web app. now it working in simple get call through the browser and postman. but it not working through the HTTP async get call.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example, although I wouldn't use HttpClient, use IHttpClientFactory so read up on that.

```
       var client = new HttpClient();

        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://itcportalapi.azurewebsites.net/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "portal/api/User/GetSecurityQuestions");
        request.Headers.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));


        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request))
        {

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            }
            else
            {

            }



        }
```

Comment: how to user IhttpClentFactory in asp.net. I think it work fine in core

Comment: This link for IHttpClientFactory https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56335928/wep-api-fails-to-return-data-from-httpclient-call/56338285#56338285